# how to add product to Shopping Cart with nodejs express and mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am building an inventory management app, and I want to create a functionality that resembles a shopping cart/product system. I am at the stage of adding a product to the cart, and can't seem to figure out a working code.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    active: Bolean,
    modifiedOn: Date,
    product: [
      {
        qunantity: String,
        name: String,
        price: number
      }
    ]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Cart", CartSchema);
```

Cart controller :

```
exports.postCart = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let cart = JSON.parse(req.body.cart);
  if (!cart) return res.json(products)
  for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    id = products[i].id.toString();
    if (cart.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      products[i].qty = cart[id]
      products.push(products[i]);
    }
  }
  return res.json(products);
})
```

Am trying to set up an upsert like function such that document is created for the provided userId and if one does not already exists. The truth is that i have tried but cant figure it out,anyone with an idea will be appreciated

Comment: Hi, don't you need to use a userId in cart schema? How will we know which cart for a user?

Comment: @SuleymanSah can you help with a snippet, I so that I can compare with what I have written

Comment: You can check my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think a userId field in the cart is a must in a shopping cart system.

So I would design my schema like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    },
    products: [
      {
        productId: Number,
        quantity: Number,
        name: String,
        price: Number
      }
    ],
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    modifiedOn: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Cart", CartSchema);
```

Note that:

1. I assume you have a User model, if your users in different model you can update the ref in userId field.
2. I changed the type of quantity field to `Number`
3. I renamed `product` field to `products` since it is an array.

Using this schema, I would create a route like this to add items to the cart:

```
router.post("/cart", async (req, res) => {
  const { productId, quantity, name, price } = req.body;

  const userId = "5de7ffa74fff640a0491bc4f"; //TODO: the logged in user id

  try {
    let cart = await Cart.findOne({ userId });

    if (cart) {
      //cart exists for user
      let itemIndex = cart.products.findIndex(p => p.productId == productId);

      if (itemIndex > -1) {
        //product exists in the cart, update the quantity
        let productItem = cart.products[itemIndex];
        productItem.quantity = quantity;
        cart.products[itemIndex] = productItem;
      } else {
        //product does not exists in cart, add new item
        cart.products.push({ productId, quantity, name, price });
      }
      cart = await cart.save();
      return res.status(201).send(cart);
    } else {
      //no cart for user, create new cart
      const newCart = await Cart.create({
        userId,
        products: [{ productId, quantity, name, price }]
      });

      return res.status(201).send(newCart);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

I assume you have already the logged in user's id, I set a hard-coded userId.

Some tests:

For the first time let's add a product to cart for a user:

```
{
    "productId": 1,
    "quantity": 1,
    "name": "product 1",
    "price": 11
}
```

The response will be like this:

```
{
    "active": true,
    "modifiedOn": "2019-12-04T19:02:12.673Z",
    "_id": "5de802bbc68b882d4803473f",
    "userId": "5de7ffa74fff640a0491bc4f",
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "5de802bbc68b882d48034740",
            "productId": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "product 1",
            "price": 11
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2019-12-04T19:02:19.567Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-12-04T19:02:19.567Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Then let's add another different product:

```
{
    "productId": 2,
    "quantity": 2,
    "name": "product 2",
    "price": 22
}
```

The response will be like this:

```
{
    "active": true,
    "modifiedOn": "2019-12-04T19:02:12.673Z",
    "_id": "5de802bbc68b882d4803473f",
    "userId": "5de7ffa74fff640a0491bc4f",
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "5de802bbc68b882d48034740",
            "productId": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "product 1",
            "price": 11
        },
        {
            "_id": "5de802e3c68b882d48034741",
            "productId": 2,
            "quantity": 2,
            "name": "product 2",
            "price": 22
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2019-12-04T19:02:19.567Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-12-04T19:02:59.703Z",
    "__v": 1
}
```

Now let's try to change the quantity to 1 for  productId = 2:

```
{
    "productId": 2,
    "quantity": 1,
    "name": "product 2",
    "price": 22
}
```

The response will be like this:

```
{
    "active": true,
    "modifiedOn": "2019-12-04T19:02:12.673Z",
    "_id": "5de802bbc68b882d4803473f",
    "userId": "5de7ffa74fff640a0491bc4f",
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": "5de802bbc68b882d48034740",
            "productId": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "product 1",
            "price": 11
        },
        {
            "_id": "5de802e3c68b882d48034741",
            "productId": 2,
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "product 2",
            "price": 22
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2019-12-04T19:02:19.567Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-12-04T19:03:42.506Z",
    "__v": 1
}
```

As you see in the response, the quantity for productId = 2 is changed to 1.

Comment: Thanks...I will check and give you feedback

Comment: great insight, your solution works perfectly! But there is a one issue, this line (const userId = "5de7ffa74fff640a0491bc4f). How do I do this programmatically without hardcoding the Id's.I know this is basic, but I just started the MERN stack and I guess I still have a lot to figure out. And insight on this?

Comment: @8SINS  that topic is a little big to mention in the comments, please search in google `express authentication` or `nodejs authentication`. For example you can read this article: https://medium.com/quick-code/handling-authentication-and-authorization-with-node-7f9548fedde8

Comment: Why this _id appear in the product, this is not a mongoose type? I think it is missing... "products": [
        {
            "_id": "5de802bbc68b882d48034740",

Comment: Though the quantity is changed to 1 , but the price remain same? How to fluctuate the price if quantity increases and decreases?

Comment: can you show your schema here as well? thanks

Comment: @MirzaIrtiza CartSchema  is already in the answer.

Comment: im confused on this line of code "router.post("/cart", async (req, res) => {
  const { productId, quantity, name, price } = req.body;"

do you have any github repository so i can understand more easily

Answer (score 3):

You Cart model should look like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let ItemSchema = new Schema(
  {
    productId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Product",
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      min: [1, "Quantity can not be less then 1."],
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    total: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model("item", ItemSchema);

const CartSchema = new Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },

    items: [ItemSchema],

    subTotal: {
      default: 0,
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model("cart", CartSchema);
```

After that you can define your add method:

```
exports.addItemToCart = async (req, res) => {
    const {
        userId,
        productId
    } = req.body;
    const quantity = Number.parseInt(req.body.quantity);

    try {
        // -------Get users Cart ------
        let cart = await Cart.findOne({
            userId: userId
        })

        //-----Get Selected Product Details ----
        const productDetails = await Product.findById(productId);

        //-- Check if cart Exists and Check the quantity if items -------
        if (!cart && quantity item.productId == productId);

            //------this removes an item from the the cart if the quantity is set to zero,We can use this method to remove an item from the list  --------
            if (indexFound !== -1 && quantity  item.total).reduce((acc, next) => acc + next);
            }

            //----------check if product exist,just add the previous quantity with the new quantity and update the total price-------
            else if (indexFound !== -1) {
                cart.items[indexFound].quantity = cart.items[indexFound].quantity + quantity;
                cart.items[indexFound].total = cart.items[indexFound].quantity * productDetails.price;
                cart.items[indexFound].price = productDetails.price
                cart.subTotal = cart.items.map(item => item.total).reduce((acc, next) => acc + next);
            }

            //----Check if Quantity is Greater than 0 then add item to items Array ----
            else if (quantity > 0) {
                cart.items.push({
                    productId: productId,
                    quantity: quantity,
                    price: productDetails.price,
                    total: parseInt(productDetails.price * quantity)
                })
                cart.subTotal = cart.items.map(item => item.total).reduce((acc, next) => acc + next);
            }
            //----if quantity of price is 0 throw the error -------
            else {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    type: "Invalid",
                    msg: "Invalid request"
                })
            }
            let data = await cart.save();
            res.status(200).json({
                type: "success",
                mgs: "Process Successful",
                data: data
            })
        }
        //------------ if there is no user with a cart...it creates a new cart and then adds the item to the cart that has been created------------
        else {
            const cartData = {
                userId: userId,
                items: [{
                    productId: productId,
                    quantity: quantity,
                    total: parseInt(productDetails.price * quantity),
                    price: productDetails.price
                }],
                subTotal: parseInt(productDetails.price * quantity)
            }
            cart = new Cart(cartData);
            let data = await cart.save();
            res.json(data);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(400).json({
            type: "Invalid",
            msg: "Something Went Wrong",
            err: err
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**i have make some change in exiting addItemToCart() function then it's working fine for me**

`exports.addItemToCart = async (req, res, next) => {

```
const { userId, itemId, note } = req.body;
let data = null;

const quantity = Number.parseInt(req.body.quantity);

let cart = await Cart.findOne({ userId: userId}); 
const productDetails = await Product.findById(itemId);

console.log("productDetails", productDetails)

//-- Check if cart Exists and Check the quantity if items -------
if (cart){
    let indexFound = cart.items.findIndex(p => p.itemId == itemId);
    console.log("Index", indexFound)
    //----------check if product exist,just add the previous quantity with the new quantity and update the total price-------
    if (indexFound != -1) {
        cart.items[indexFound].quantity = cart.items[indexFound].quantity + quantity;
        cart.items[indexFound].total = cart.items[indexFound].quantity * productDetails.price;
        cart.items[indexFound].price = productDetails.price
        cart.subTotal = cart.items.map(item => item.total).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
    }
    //----Check if Quantity is Greater than 0 then add item to items Array ----
    else if (quantity > 0) {
        cart.items.push({
            itemId: itemId,
            quantity: quantity,
            price: productDetails.price,
            total: parseInt(productDetails.price * quantity).toFixed(2),
        })
        cart.subTotal = cart.items.map(item => item.total).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr);
    }
    //----if quantity of price is 0 throw the error -------
    else {
        return res.status(400).json({
            code: 400,
            message: "Invalid request"                
        })
    }

    data = await cart.save();
}
//------if there is no user with a cart then it creates a new cart and then adds the item to the cart that has been created---------
else {
    const cartData = {
        userId: userId,
        items: [{
            itemId: itemId,
            quantity: quantity,
            total: parseInt(productDetails.price * quantity),
            price: productDetails.price,
            note: note
            
        }],
        subTotal: parseInt(productDetails.price * quantity)
    }
    cart = new Cart(cartData);
    data = await cart.save();
}

return res.status(200).send({ 
    code: 200,
    message: "Add to Cart successfully!",
    data: data
});
```

}
`

Comment: do you have any github repository for example, with complete road map. i m having issue in schema from server

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the accepted answer, here's my code with complete CRUD:

**Controller:**

```
const { isValidObjectId } = require("mongoose");
const { Cart } = require("../models/cart.model");
const { User } = require("../models/user.model");

exports.addItemToCart = async (req, res) => {
  let userId = req.params.userId;
  let user = await User.exists({ _id: userId });

  if (!userId || !isValidObjectId(userId) || !user)
    return res.status(400).send({ status: false, message: "Invalid user ID" });

  let productId = req.body.productId;
  if (!productId)
    return res.status(400).send({ status: false, message: "Invalid product" });

  let cart = await Cart.findOne({ userId: userId });

  if (cart) {
    let itemIndex = cart.products.findIndex((p) => p.productId == productId);

    if (itemIndex > -1) {
      let productItem = cart.products[itemIndex];
      productItem.quantity += 1;
      cart.products[itemIndex] = productItem;
    } else {
      cart.products.push({ productId: productId, quantity: 1 });
    }
    cart = await cart.save();
    return res.status(200).send({ status: true, updatedCart: cart });
  } else {
    const newCart = await Cart.create({
      userId,
      products: [{ productId: productId, quantity: 1 }],
    });

    return res.status(201).send({ status: true, newCart: newCart });
  }
};

exports.getCart = async (req, res) => {
  let userId = req.params.userId;
  let user = await User.exists({ _id: userId });

  if (!userId || !isValidObjectId(userId) || !user)
    return res.status(400).send({ status: false, message: "Invalid user ID" });

  let cart = await Cart.findOne({ userId: userId });
  if (!cart)
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send({ status: false, message: "Cart not found for this user" });

  res.status(200).send({ status: true, cart: cart });
};

exports.decreaseQuantity = async (req, res) => {
  // use add product endpoint for increase quantity
  let userId = req.params.userId;
  let user = await User.exists({ _id: userId });
  let productId = req.body.productId;

  if (!userId || !isValidObjectId(userId) || !user)
    return res.status(400).send({ status: false, message: "Invalid user ID" });

  let cart = await Cart.findOne({ userId: userId });
  if (!cart)
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send({ status: false, message: "Cart not found for this user" });

  let itemIndex = cart.products.findIndex((p) => p.productId == productId);

  if (itemIndex > -1) {
    let productItem = cart.products[itemIndex];
    productItem.quantity -= 1;
    cart.products[itemIndex] = productItem;
    cart = await cart.save();
    return res.status(200).send({ status: true, updatedCart: cart });
  }
  res
    .status(400)
    .send({ status: false, message: "Item does not exist in cart" });
};

exports.removeItem = async (req, res) => {
  let userId = req.params.userId;
  let user = await User.exists({ _id: userId });
  let productId = req.body.productId;

  if (!userId || !isValidObjectId(userId) || !user)
    return res.status(400).send({ status: false, message: "Invalid user ID" });

  let cart = await Cart.findOne({ userId: userId });
  if (!cart)
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send({ status: false, message: "Cart not found for this user" });

  let itemIndex = cart.products.findIndex((p) => p.productId == productId);
  if (itemIndex > -1) {
    cart.products.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    cart = await cart.save();
    return res.status(200).send({ status: true, updatedCart: cart });
  }
  res
    .status(400)
    .send({ status: false, message: "Item does not exist in cart" });
};
```

**Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  productId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Product",
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
});

const cartSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  products: [itemSchema],
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  total: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  __v: { type: Number, select: false },
});

exports.Cart = mongoose.model("Cart", cartSchema);
```

**Routes:**

```
const express = require("express");
const cartRouter = express.Router();
const cartController = require("../controllers/cart.controller");

cartRouter.post("/:userId", cartController.addItemToCart);
cartRouter.get("/:userId", cartController.getCart);
cartRouter.patch("/:userId", cartController.decreaseQuantity);
cartRouter.delete("/:userId", cartController.removeItem);

module.exports = cartRouter;
```