# update the quantity and totalPrice property value in my cart

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

verything is working great except the quantity. I want to update the quantity and totalPrice property value in my cart schema but it is not working.

Below are the used code snippets for the cart backend -

- Cart Schema (cartModel.js) :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
    items: [
      {
        productId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "Product",
        },
        quantity: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        price: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        type: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    modifiedOn: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Cart", CartSchema);
```

- Cart Controller (cartController.js) :

```
exports.addToCart = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.body.id;
  let cart = await Cart.findOne({ userId: req.user._id });
  let cartProduct = await Cart.findOne({ productId: req.body.id });
  const type = req.body.type;
  const user = req.user._id;

  if (cart) {
    if (cartProduct) {
      let itemIndex = cart.items.findIndex((p) => p.productId == id);
      cart.items[itemIndex].type = req.body.type;
      let productItem = cart.items[itemIndex];
      let quantity = 1;
      let prevAmount = productItem.price;

      if (productItem.type === "increment") {
        productItem.quantity += quantity;
        productItem.price += prevAmount;
        cart.items[itemIndex] = productItem;
      }

      if (
        productItem.type === "decrement" &&
        productItem.quantity > 1 &&
        productItem.price > 0
      ) {
        productItem.quantity -= quantity;
        productItem.price -= prevAmount;
      }

      await cart.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

      res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        cart,
      });
    } else {
      const product = await Product.findById(req.body.id);

      const { _id, name, price, rating, images } = product;

      let quantity = 1;
      cart.items.push({ productId: _id, quantity, name, price, type });
    }

    cart = await cart.save();
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      cart,
    });
  } else {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.body.id);

    const { _id, name, price, rating, images } = product;

    let quantity = 1;

    //no cart for user, create new cart
    const newCart = await Cart.create({
      userId: user,
      items: [{ productId: _id, quantity, name, price, type }],
    });

    return res.status(201).send(newCart);
  }
});
```

- Product Model (productModel.js) :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter product Name."],
    trim: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter product Description."],
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, "Please Enter product Price."],
    maxLength: [8, "Price cannot exceed 8 characters."],
  },
  rating: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  images: [
    {
      public_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      url: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter product Category."],
  },
  Stock: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter product Stock Status."],
    maxLength: [4, "Stock cannot exceed 4 characters."],
    default: 1,
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please Enter gender."],
  },
  numOfReviews: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  reviews: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

Comment: Why do you keep only one product in cart schema? Check this answer to get some ideas:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59183300/11717458

Comment: Hey there!! Suleyman I've changed it and its working file as expected, thank you for the suggestion. I'm still facing the problem of not getting to update the existing collection property in my db (quantity and price property). Can you please help me with that. Good Day :)